# Any way to create function/method in SQL for combining columns in the SELECT?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

Wrote a great simple function in SQL that apparently is not usable (or advisable) in my SELECT statement.

Have some intelligence behind combining Combinations of Company Name and Contact Name in our select and I find it's repeating across several views.  Being a programmer, of course the right thing is to encapsulate that functionality for reuse across all views I'm created.  But alas, from my searching it does not appear possible or recommended, at least not with UDFs.

The question: **Is there any way to select the return value of a method/function/chunk of reusable code where I pass it the value of columns for each row...** Or do I truly have to copy/paste the logic into each select statement?

```
SELECT formatName(company, contact, ' - ') as Name FROM company join contacts...
```

I know I can do this on the client (eventually), but client changes are not in scope for this phase of the project.

*I guess I typed more in this question than just cutting and pasting a CASE statement into each view, but reuse is ingrained if me of course. :)*

Comment: What are you trying to do with these columns? Is it just string concatenation or do you have some other formatting needed?

Comment: @SteveD - Either one can be null or blank, so it's like if both are valid, concatenate them... and if only one or the other just that one, etc... Simple logic, but repeated.

Answer (score 1):

A better performing and DRY method to accomplish this is with a [computed column](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/specify-computed-columns-in-a-table?view=sql-server-2017).

> A computed column is a virtual column that is not physically stored in
>   the table, unless the column is marked PERSISTED. A computed column
>   expression can use data from other columns to calculate a value for
>   the column to which it belongs. You can specify an expression for a
>   computed column in SQL Server 2017 by using SQL Server Management
>   Studio or Transact-SQL.

You can make this [column persisted as well](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-table-computed-column-definition-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

> PERSISTED Specifies that the Database Engine will physically store the
>   computed values in the table, and update the values when any other
>   columns on which the computed column depends are updated. Marking a
>   computed column as PERSISTED allows an index to be created on a
>   computed column that is deterministic, but not precise. For more
>   information, see Indexes on Computed Columns. Any computed columns
>   used as partitioning columns of a partitioned table must be explicitly
>   marked PERSISTED. computed_column_expression must be deterministic
>   when PERSISTED is specified.

```
alter table company add FullName as (FirstName + '-' + LastName) persisted;
```

Then, you could just add this column in your `SELECT` can can even query against it, if it's persisted.

Comment: Thanks for the lead... Downside is this is for SQL 2008 and unless I can put more code in there than simple concatenation, it won't work for our needs...  Also this is part of a view, with the data coming from Company and Contact to produce the combined value. :(  Good tip though and something else to keep in my toolbox for other needs when possible.

Comment: well. you could create a view that has your FullName logic and query it instead of the base table, which would keep you from using a scalar function

Comment: Which is the source of the original question.  Several of the views I'm creating all need this same logic... which is what I'm hoping to avoid.

Oh well, it's looking like it's not doable... apart from creating possible a single view that has the concatenated/calculated value, then joining to that in addition to the source tables for other information.  At that point, it's more convoluted than just cutting and pasting the CASE statement in each view creation.  Thanks again.

Comment: Yeah and querying nested views is a performance nightmare. I'd opt for the `case`

Answer (score 1):

What you can do is create a view that behaves like a table. Meaning it would have the performance of a table, can have indexes added etc.  This view can have any of the columns of the underlying base table plus you can add calculated columns, such as [name]. This is accomplished by adding WITH SCHEMABINDING when creating the view.  This view can then be used in lieu of the base table in all of your queries.

Here is an example.
The underlying base table with data:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.company (
    companyid int IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    company varchar(50) NULL,
    contact varchar(50) NULL,
 CONSTRAINT PK_company PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED  (companyid ASC) 
) ON FG1
```

The view containing WITH SCHEMABINDING:

```
CREATE view dbo.VW_company WITH SCHEMABINDING AS 
SELECT companyid, 
CASE WHEN RTRIM(ISNULL(company,'')) <> '' AND RTRIM(ISNULL(contact,'')) <> '' THEN company +' - '+ contact
    WHEN RTRIM(ISNULL(company,'')) <> '' THEN company
    WHEN RTRIM(ISNULL(contact,'')) <> '' THEN contact
    ELSE '' END as [Name]
FROM dbo.company
```

This view can now be used everywhere the table is used, without a performance hit.  Furthermore, the calculated column [Name] can actually have an index added to it!  That's something you cannot do with a function.